# Re-run command with prepended text from bash history

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, history

How do I repeat the last bash command with some text pre-pended to the front of it.

So if the previous command was:

```
$ ls /somedir
```

I want to run the following command utilizing the bash history to prevent retyping / copy & pasting:

```
$ sudo /somedir
```

Bonus, how about appending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `sudo` you can re-run the same command as above by using the double bang syntax.

```
ls /somedir
sudo !!
```

will run `sudo ls /somedir`

If you just want to use the same path then use `!$`

```
ls /somedir
ls -l !$
```

will run `ls -l /somedir`

Finally you can re-run commands from history by using `ctrl+r` to run a reverse-i-search of your bash history.